# How early can I get access to the requested post in a WordPress plugin?

Tags: wordpress

What is the earliest WordPress action/hook where I can get access to information about the post requested?

Based on a custom field in the post, I need to disable several plugins.  I can do this in the `options_actions_plugins` filter, but that fires *early* (before even `wp`).

I need to find an action that fires before `options_actions_plugins` in which I can get access to the requested post data, and figure out if I should disable plugins or not.

What action am I looking for?